# After running `create-react-app` and `npm run eject`, I cannot run `npm start`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm using macOS Sierra. After running `create-react-app` and `npm run eject`, I cannot run `npm start`. It returns the following error message:

```
> burger-builder@0.1.0 start /Users/.../
> node scripts/start.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:573
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'babel-loader'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
    at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:30:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../config/webpack.config.dev.js:145:29)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../scripts/start.js:31:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:678:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:589:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:528:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! burger-builder@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the burger-builder@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/.../.npm/_logs/2018-06-02T15_55_35_219Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Try running `npm install` once again, and make sure that `npm start` command exists in package.json

Comment: @AjayGupta It works like a charm. Thank you.